# Could a sheet of plasma ejected from the sun's surface magnetically reconnect with itself and eject bits of itself which then also reconnect?

Tags: the-sun, coronal-mass-ejection

Could the Corona of the sun be getting heated by large sheets of plasma ejecting smaller sheets and these in turn ejecting smaller sheets ?

Answer (score 2):

> Could the Corona of the sun be getting heated by large sheets of plasma ejecting smaller sheets and these in turn ejecting smaller sheets?

I will rephrase the question to:  Could [magnetic reconnection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reconnection) be responsible for the heating of the solar [corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_corona)?

The answer is yes, it is likely a major source of the energy conversion from electromagnetic to particle random kinetic energy (i.e., heat).  Is it the only mechanism?  No, most likely not.

> Could a sheet of plasma ejected from the sun's surface magnetically reconnect with itself and eject bits of itself which then also reconnect?

Well, there are large blob-like eruptions of [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) from the Sun on a semi-regular basis called [coronal mass ejections (CMEs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection).  These are known to have regions within undergoing magnetic reconnection (e.g., see https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2023ApJ...953...15F/abstract).